# Why would a closed generic type not be returned by Assembly.GetTypes()?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I have created a generic `JavaScriptConverter` derivation for a custom generic class (`TabularList<>`) which I have dubbed `ITabularConverter<>`. The `ITabularConverter` uses reflection to retrieve all of the closed types derived from the `TabularList<>` generic type definition to inform the JavaScriptSerializer that it is capable of converting all closed types of `ITabularConverter<>`. That code looks like this:

```
public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
{
    get
    {
        var type = typeof (TabularList<>);
        var itabulars = Assembly.GetAssembly(type).GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsGenericType 
                && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == type);
        return itabulars;
    }
}
```

The problem is, even though there is at least one closed type of TabularList<> in existence by the time this code executes, only the open generic type definition is returned by the above code. The same is true when I expand the search to all currently loaded assemblies.

What's even stranger is that if I examine the call stack, I can see where the JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize method is being invoked and use the immediate window to examine the object being serialized and prove that a closed version of the generic definition exists. Yet, when I execute the following code in the Immediate Window, the result is `false`:

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(obj.TabularListProp.GetType())
    .GetTypes()
    .Contains(obj.TabularListProp.GetType());
```

So I retrieve the assembly in which the closed generic is defined and then look for the closed generic type among the types defined by that assembly, and the closed type is not found. How does that make any sense?

Here is the declaration of `TabularList<>`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Central.Claims.UX.ClaimWFMgrViewModel
{
    [Serializable]
    public class TabularList<T> : List<T>, ITabular
    {

        private List<List<object>> _tableView;

        [XmlIgnore]
        public List<List<object>> TableView
        {
            get { return GetTableView(); }
        }

        private List<KeyValuePair<string, Func<object, object>>> Schema { get; set; }  
        public TabularList()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public TabularList(IEnumerable<T> source) : base(source)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            RefreshTableView = true;
            var type = typeof(T);

            if (Schemas.ContainsKey(type.Name))
            {
                Schema = Schemas[type.Name];
            }
            else
            {
                Schema = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Func<object, object>>>();
            }
        }

        protected List<List<object>> GetTableView()
        {    
            GetSchema();
            BuildTable();

            return _tableView;
        }

        private void GetSchema()
        {
            if (this.Any())
            {
                var properties = this.First().GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    var getter = property.GetGetMethod();

                    Schema.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Func<object, object>>(
                        property.Name,
                        (Func<object, object>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (Func<object, object>), getter)
                        ));
                }
            }
        }

        private void BuildTable()
        {
            _tableView = new List<List<object>>();

            foreach (var item in this)
            {
                TableView.Add(ToTableRow(item));
            }
        }

        private List<object> ToTableRow(T item)
        {
            var row = new List<object>();

            foreach (var column in Schema)
            {
                row.Add(column.Value(item));
            }

            return row;
        }
    }     
}
```

Based on the answers provided here, I have rephrased this question in the SO question [How to retrieve a list of all closed generic types generated by the .NET runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217036/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-all-closed-generic-types-generated-by-the-net-runtime)

Comment: Does the type exist in the same assembly in which the `TabularList<>` type is?

Comment: Post your class declaration and are you sure `GetTypes` doesn't return it? Or your where condition filters it? `IsGenericType` will be false for types which doesn't take any type parameter.

Comment: @DavidG - No, the type is defined in another project in the same solution whereas these code snippets are in a web application.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - Class declaration posted. In this case I'm just using `GetTypes().Contains(type)`. When I originally posted the question I was using Linq, but I switched to `.Contains()` because the immediate window cannot handle lambda expressions.

Comment: The documentation for the Type.Assembly property says: "If the current Type object represents a constructed generic type, this property returns the assembly that contains the generic type definition." The documentation for the Assembly.GetAssembly(Type) method does not say this, but it should, since it does the same thing. (It's just bad documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that reflection is just querying *metadata*, so any information contained within it is purely compile-type information.  The fact that you have an instance of `TabularList<SomeType>)` does *not* change the metadata contained within the assembly that defines it.

A closed generic type is *not* defined within either the assembly that defined the open generic type, nor the assembly that creates that particular closed type.

Would you expect to find metadata for *every possible* closed definition of `List<T>` within `mscorlib`?  Would you expect to find it in an assembly that create a `List<int>` variable?

Note that it *does* work the other way - if you call

```
Assembly a = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(List<int>));
```

you get the Assembly

```
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

So you might be able to reverse your logic - rather than searching for all closed types within an assembly, look for the assembly of the closed type to see if it's "supported".

Comment: *smacks forehead*  It just dawned on me that the examples of reflecting on closed types I've seen in other similar StackOverflow questions involved generic types that were closed at compile time. This all suddenly makes sense. So is there any way to query the runtime for all closed definitions of a generic type?

Comment: @DanielArant I'm not sure what you mean - can you post an example of your type that is "close at compile time"? You could probably trim a lot of the irrelevant methods in your post as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, the nature of the JavaScriptConverter is such that it will only use a converter if there is an equality between the type being converted and one of the types returned by the SupportedTypes property.

Comment: By "closed at compile time" I simply mean that a type argument is supplied in a derived type definition, such as `CloseGeneric : List<int>`

Comment: @DanielArant If you have a non-generic class that derives from a generic type, then you can find that type in the type list of the assembly.

Comment: @Poke - Correct. But that is not the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @DanielArant You could extract `List<int>` from the inheritance tree of `CloseGeneric`.  Or you could provide all supported closed types directly in `SupportedTypes`.

Answer (score 1):

Generic types generally don’t exist in an assembly. If that was the case, then *every* possible combination for the type argument would need to be present, which very quickly gives you an infinite amount of different types.

So instead, the generic type *definition* is the concrete type that exists in the assembly. You can get the generic type definition by calling `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` on the type:

```
Type t = typeof(List<int>);
t.Assembly.GetTypes().Contains(t); // false
t.Assembly.GetTypes().Contains(t.GetGenericTypeDefinition()); // true
```

Comment: This is along the same lines of @DStanley's answer. Is there a way to dynamically retrieve a list of closed types generated by the runtime? The JavaScriptSerializer will only use a converter if one of the types returned by the SupportedTypes property equals the type currently being converted, so it's not good enough to return the generic type definition.

Comment: What do you mean by “closed type generated by the runtime”? Generic type arguments are inserted at compile time (unless you use reflection). If you want to generate all possible `X<T>` from `X<>`, then you should annotate the `T`s in some way so you can identify them, and then build `X<T>`s from that list.

Comment: According to MSDN documentation, closed generic types are created by the runtime: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a6ta2h.aspx