# How to retrieve a list of all closed generic types generated by the .NET runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

According to MSDN documentation, the .NET runtime will dynamically generate closed types based on generic type definitions on an as-needed basis.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a6ta2h.aspx

Is it possible to retrieve a collection of `System.Type` instances corresponding to those runtime-generated closed types?

Comment: You can use reflection to build a list.  It will however be a manual process.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible using normal Reflection from `Assembly.GetTypes` - did you ever come up with a working solution? I am trying to find the closed types for anonymous types.

Answer (score 2):

Build the list dynamically using the static constructor.  This is not thread safe but the only thread contention happens when the static constructor runs right after the each closed type is first created, so that might not be an issue depending on how your code is constructed.

i.e. if all of your initial access to these generic types happens in a single thread, you have nothing to worry about.

The static constructor runs once for every closed type that is created.  When the closed type is created and the static constructor run, you can store the type in a static non-generic list variable.  (You cannot use a generic static or you will have a separate list for every closed type)

```
public class MyStaticClass
{
    public static List<Type> ClosedTypes = new List<Type>();
}

public class MyGenericType<T>
{
    static MyGenericType()
    {
        MyStaticClass.ClosedTypes.Add(typeof(MyGenericType<T>));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the thread safety issue? Doesn't a static constructor *always* run "right after each closed type is first created?"

Comment: Yes.  Static constructors are thread-safe.  The contention is for the static List variable.  If 2 static constructors ran at the same time on different threads, and the list needed to auto-resize at that exact moment, there is a chance that one of the types wouldn't make it into your list.